# Error on set background Images on Excel by XlsxWriter

Tags: python-3.x, excel, report, xlsxwriter, odoo-12

I am trying to set an background image on excel report using Python XlsxWriter. But I am getting an error -

> AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_background'

What I am trying -

```
    wb = Workbook(stream, {'in_memory': True})
    sheet_cover = wb.add_worksheet("Cover")
    image_url = werkzeug.urls.url_join(base_url,
                                       '/test_module/static/src/img/cover-image.png')
    image_data = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(image_url).read())
    sheet_cover.set_background(image_data, is_byte_stream=True)
```

What I am trying to achieve -
[image]

Got stuck on this please help.
thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possibly you have an older version of XlsxWriter where that method wasn’t supported. It was only added in a recent version. Try upgrade to the latest version and try again.

Comment: Upgraded version. Now the previous error is gone. Thanks 
But I can't see my image in the excel file. Can you please suggest me how can I place the image on a special area like the image in description.

Comment: The image you show above isn't what Excel refers to as a worksheet background image. That would cover the entire worksheet. Are you just trying to insert a single image (in which case have a look at the insert_image() method)? Otherwise how would you do what you want to do in Excel?

Comment: With insert_image . images is always coming in the foreground and it's hiding the cell information. But I need that image in background and over that I have to add some information. Is it possible to sent image in background with insert_image().?

Comment: No. Unfortunately that isn’t possible with XlsxWriter.